# Select date from date column

Tags: r

I have a data like this;

```
"Date"       "Observe"        "Simulation"

1/01/1985         9.8          7.65

16/01/1985        7.5             5.74

1/02/1985         5.6             3.35

16/02/1985        4.6             3.15
```

I am using `R`. I want to make a subset selecting data only for a particular date (i.e. 16th of each month). How can I do this?

Any help you can provide will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Something like this.

Read in the tabular data from file, I am assuming your file really looks like you have it, but without the empty lines.

```
dat <- read.table("file.txt", header = TRUE,
  colClasses = c("character", "numeric", "numeric"))
```

Convert the Date column to a known Date class, specifying explicitly the format used. See ?strptime for the codes available.

```
dat$gDate <- as.Date(dat$Date, "%d/%m/%Y")
```

Create a logical vector to match TRUE/FALSE with month day equal to 16.

```
datesub <- (as.POSIXlt(dat$Date)$mday) == 16
```

Subset the original data with the logical vector, discarding rows where the day is not "16".

```
dat16only <- dat[datesub, ]
```

See `?read.table` `?as.Date` `?DateTimeClasses` `?Comparison` and `?Extract`

Comment: I had an error in here first time with yday instead of mday, should be fixed now

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach - using `data.table` and `lubridate` packages. I'm assuming you want to do multuple operations on the subset that you get - it's really easy to do those with the `data.table` package:

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)
dat <- data.table(dte = sapply(c(1:15, 12:25, 20:31, 1:31), 
                               function(z) paste(z,"01/1985",sep="/")), 
                  observe = rnorm(n = 72, mean = 1, sd = 12),
                  simul = rnorm(n = 72, mean = 0.5, sd = 10))

dat$dte <- as.Date(dat$dte, "%d/%m/%Y")

# subset for a certain day - 20
dat[day(dte) == 20]

# Aggregate by day 
new_dat <- dat[, lapply(.SD, mean), by = day(dte)]
```

EDIT: I didn't realize that I'm answering such an old question, oh well.